# Hide Approve/Reject button for the user who has created request

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, custom-actions

I want to Hide the Approve/Reject button from the top ribbon, specifically for the users who has created the request and placed for approval.

Currently, If user ABC has created request and XYZ has to approve it, the Approve/Reject button appears for ABC also and he can process approval.

Please assist me to resolve this. I have created workflow from the designer and I am using SP FOUNDATION 2010.

Thanks.